# HTML Center image in flex circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a problem. In my angular project I have the following code:

```js
onChange(event: any) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
        this.url = event.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

```css
#upload-icon {
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.image-content {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}

input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}

.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
}


img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<label class="custom-file-upload">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment" class="fileInput" id="file-input"
           (change)="onChange($event)">
    <div class="image-content" *ngIf="!url">
        <i class="far fa-images"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="image-content" *ngIf="url">
        <label for="file-input">
            <img [src]="url"/>
        </label>
    </div>
</label>
```

Now what I am trying to do is create a circle with a border of 1 px. In that cicle I want to show an icon, to show that you can upload an image. When you click on the circle you can select your file. When you hit upload, the circle will be filled with your image, but when you click your image again, you can reuplaod an image. The problem is that the icon and image are not centered:
[image]
and
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Image has not a suitable dimension for this circle... you have 2 options, 1) decrease the width and set `height: auto` 2) use `width: 100%` and `height: auto`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set 100% as max height and max width to image and alternate icon, and replace `text-align: center;` to `align-items: center;` for `.custom-file-upload`

Updated HTML -

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<label class="custom-file-upload">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment" class="fileInput" id="file-input"
           (change)="onChange($event)">
    <div class="image-content" *ngIf="!url">
        <i class="far fa-images icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="image-content" *ngIf="url">
        <label for="file-input">
            <img [src]="url"/>
        </label>
    </div>
</label>
```

Updated CSS -

```
#upload-icon {
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

 .image-content {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

input[type='file'] {
  display: none;
}

.custom-file-upload {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img,
.icon {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

[Working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uuhnbu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

If you want to cover entire division, use image as background image - [see example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvjlr9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Just one question. How can I let the image fill the entire circle. When I upload a rectangluar image, I want it to be zoomed until it is using the full circle. I added `object-fit: fill;` to the `img` class, but that doesn't work

Comment: Sure, please see my updated answer with link. You can do more experiment with background properties in CSS like, background-size, background-position etc. as per your requirement.

Comment: Just 1 thing, your background image is an image from internet, but I am using font-awesome icons using `<i>` is this possible as well?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Updated my example link, replace default image with your icon and add the same class as well.